# copyfile(), ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

I know my tkinter buttons are horribly inefficient but i don't care so please don't comment on that.

https://pastebin.com/4e7LXY2t

copyfile() gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\PKSun\test.py", line 80, in <module>
    copyfile(str(root)+'/romfs/a'+paths[i],a+'/'+dirs[i])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 103, in copyfile
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 88, in _samefile
    return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\genericpath.py", line 96, in samefile
    s1 = os.stat(f1)
ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path
```

Im using windows 7 and python 3.6.1, i also intend to build this into an EXE file if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is not clear about the error? `\0` is a NULL char. You probably want **raw strings**: put `r` as prefix in the string literals.

Comment: oh, i feel stupid, i forgot \0 denoted a NULL, thanks haha.
just to check, i can just change
copyfile(str(root)+'/romfs/a'+paths[i],a+'/'+dirs[i])
to
copyfile(r+str(root)+'/romfs/a'+paths[i],r+a+'/'+dirs[i])
or do i just have to put it before every element in the arrays?

Comment: Write it as `r'\0\1\1'` instead of `'\0\1\1'`.

Comment: nooo.... since then the string is already constructed.

Comment: okay, Thanks, i feel really stupid. this program took longer than i care to admit for me to figure out xD